# R: JSON Package - importing data & missing values / null

Tags: arrays, json, r, import, null

I am reading in data with the JSON package.

Basically, the data has the following format:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
{"a": null,"b":2,"c":3}
```

I am storing the data as follows in R:

```
DAT<-data.table(read.csv("D:/file.csv"))
i<-1
#create unified variable names
while (i<=nrow(DAT)) {
OUT[[i]]<-fromJSON(as.character(DAT[i]$results))
vnames<-c(vnames,names(OUT[[i]]))
i<-i+1
}
#create the corresponding content 
content <- NULL
Applicant <- NULL
  i<-1
  while (i<=nrow(DAT)) {
    temp<-fromJSON(as.character(DAT[i]$results))
    laenge <- length(fromJSON(as.character(DAT[i]$results)))
    for(j in 1:laenge)
    {
      content_new <- as.character(temp[[j]])
      content <- c(content, content_new)
    }
    i <- i+1
  }
```

Then I want to join the lists via (in order to have the data in the typical format):

```
assets_mren = data.frame(asset_class=vnames, value=content)
```

Yet I receive an **error message** stating that **vnames** and **content** have **different number of rows**. I believe that the problem is **"null"** in the data to be read in. Do you have an idea how to read in **"null"** above or how to better read in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is null. You get different structure for each row.

```
ll <- '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
       {"a": null,"b":2,"c":3}'
res <- lapply(ll,function(x)str(fromJSON(x)))
 Named num [1:3] 1 2 3                       ## named vector for the first line
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
List of 3
 $ a: NULL                                   ## list for the second line
 $ b: num 2
 $ c: num 3
```

So you have to homogenise the output of each line. Here 2 options:

1- replace null by a dummy values (0 or -1) for example:

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(gsub("null",-1,ll)))
do.call(rbind,lapply(ll,function(x)
    fromJSON(x)))
     a b c
[1,]  1 2 3
[2,] -1 2 3    ## res[res==-1] <- NA to replace dummy value
```

2- keep the null but you should use `rbind.fill` to get a data.frame:

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(gsub("null",-1,ll)))
do.call(rbind,lapply(ll,function(x)
  fromJSON(x)))
ll <- '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
{"a": null,"b":2,"c":3}'
ll <- readLines(textConnection(ll))
res <- lapply(ll,function(x)
    as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(unlist(fromJSON(x))))))
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(res)

   a b c
1  1 2 3
2 NA 2 3
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot for your answer. Your example works fine. Yet, when I read "my data", I get the following error message: **Error from fromJSON(x) : unexpected character 'c'**

Comment: @user3021506 hard to help you without data.